# React Native - Problem Using Image Component

Tags: typescript, react-native, image, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use the Image component in my flatlist however i get this error when i try to use it.

"JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property."
[image: Error]

My Code:

```
export default function FlatList() {
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
<View>
  <Image source={{ uri: item.picture }} />
</View>;
};

return(
 <View>
  <FlatList
    data={routeArray}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  />
</View>
);}
```

Comment: add  @types/react like npm install it or yarn add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to use the React Native `Image` type, rather than the `HTMLImageElement` type. Make sure you have installed React Native to your project, then add the following to your imports:

```
import { Image } from "react-native";
```

See React Native Image [Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/react-native/image/) for a complete use example.